# C# Game Engine - Adding an Instance of a Transform Class to a List of Components in the Game-Object Class & being able to access its methods

Tags: c#, project, game-engine

I am building a C# Game Engine for a College Project and I am facing some problems, I have a class called **GameObject** that contains a List of **Component** (Which is another Class), I created a class that saves a Vector3 Struct called **Transform** which Inherits from the **Component** class.

Now when I try to add the New Instance of Transform into the Component List in Gameobject it doesn't allow me to access the internal methods of the Transform class or do something like get the X coordinate:

```
// This is the List inside the class GameObject
public List<Component> Components = new List<Component>();

// This is the new Instance of Transform
Transform transform = new Transform();

// This is how I tried to add the new object to the list above
AddComponent(transform);
public void AddComponent(object component)
{
    Components.Add((Component)component);
}


// This Works
Console.WriteLine(transform.Position.X);
// However, this line bellow does not allow me to use 'Position'
Console.WriteLine(Components[0]);
```

**The Full Code is Listed Bellow for a Clearer Picture**

*GameObject Class:*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace BoBo3D_George.R_Dor.S
{
    public class GameObject
    {
        // GameObject Class Fields
        public List<Component> Components = new List<Component>();
        private bool _isEnabled = true;
        private string _name;
        
        // ------------------------------

        // GameObject Class Constructor
        public GameObject(string name)
        {
            _name = name;
            Transform transform = new Transform();
            AddComponent(transform);
            Rigidbody rigidBody = new Rigidbody();
            AddComponent(rigidBody);
            Console.WriteLine(transform.Position.X);
            Console.WriteLine(Components[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(Components[1]);
        }


        // ------------------------------

        // GameObject Class Properties
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return "Object Name: " + _name;
            }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
            }
        }

        public bool IsEnabled
        {
            get
            {
                return _isEnabled;
            }
        }

        // ------------------------------

        // GameObject Class Methods
        public void Disable()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Enable()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Destroy()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void AddComponent(object component)
        {
            Components.Add((Component)component);
        }

        public void RemoveComponent(object component)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object GetComponent(int compNum)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

*Component, Transform & RigidBody Classes:*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace BoBo3D_George.R_Dor.S
{
    public abstract class Component : IComponent
    {
        // IComponent Interface Implementation in Component Class
        public void OnDisable()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnEnable()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Update(float deltaTime)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    // Transform Class Componnent
    class Transform : Component
    {
        public Vector3 Position = new Vector3() { X = 0, Y = 0, Z = 0 };

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string info;
            info = Position.ToString();
            return info;
        }
    }

    // Rigidbody Class Componnent
    class Rigidbody : Component
    {
        private bool _useGravity = false;
        private float _g = Physics.Gravity();
        private float _timeScale = 0;
        private float _fallVelocity = 0;
        private float _gravityScale = 0;
        private string _info;

        public bool UsingGravity
        {
            get
            {
                return _useGravity;
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Gravity:({_useGravity})\n" + _info;
        }

        public bool ToggleGravity()
        {
            if (_useGravity == true)
            {
                _useGravity = false;
            }
            else
            {
                _useGravity = true;
            }
            return _useGravity;
        }

        public float ActiveGravity()
        {
            if (_useGravity == true)
            {
                _timeScale++;
                _fallVelocity = _g * _timeScale;
                _gravityScale = (_g/2) * (_timeScale * _timeScale);
            }
            else
            {
                _timeScale = 0;
                _fallVelocity = 0;
                _gravityScale = 0;
            }

            _info = "Time:" + _timeScale + "\nVelocity:" + _fallVelocity + "\nHeight:" + _gravityScale;
            return _gravityScale;
        }

        public void ApplyConstantForce(float incrementation, Vector3 directionInV3)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Components[0] is a Component.  Since Position is a property of Transform you would first need to cast the Component to Transform in order to have access to Position.

Comment: @hijinxbassist Thank you for the answer!
I understood what I have to do from your answer but I do not get how to do the casting, can you help me with that?

Comment: I imagine that Transform is a required component of GameObject, in which case i would leave it out of the Component array and keep it typed as Transform in the GameObject class.   If, however, you want to keep transform in the component array, first you need to check if that component can be cast to transform;  `if (thisComponent is Transform)` or the flavor i personally use `var transform = thisComponent as Transform;  if (transform != null)`  or the error prone direct casting `(Transform)thisComponent`

Comment: @hijinxbassist I implemented the Casting Checker and it finally worked, thank you!

Comment: Great to hear!  Glad to help :)